# Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0-rc2-final could not be resolved

Tags: angular, .net-core

I created a new .net core project & tried adding to the project.json file:

Microsoft.AspNerCore.StaticFiles but got the following Error.

My goal is to get it working w/ Angular & I was following [these direction in step 2](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/#commentlist-container).

[image]

The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0-rc2-final could not be resolved.   Angular2DotNet  c:\Users\Reynald\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Angular2DotNet\src\Angular2DotNet\project.json   10

Same error occurs if I chose StaticFiles version "1.0.0"

Using VS 2015 Community on Win 10. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: right click on project and Restore Packages.. that worked for me!